# How to filter Post using Meta Data REST API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I want to list post that filtered by Meta Data

I have tried many solutions i found here but i can't make it work.

The last solution i tried is to add this to my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'rest_product_query', function( $args, $request ){
    if ( $stocks = $request->get_param( 'stocks' ) ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = 'stocks';
        $args['meta_value'] = $stocks;
    }
    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

and i use this:

```
.../wp-json/wc/v3/products?status=publish&stocks=Ships%20From%20Abroad&consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=xxx
```

It list all the products, but not filtered. How can i make it work? Thanks!

Comment: It might be more efficient to store your `stocks` custom field as a custom taxonomy, that would make it significantly easier to query for, and make those queries much much faster